# Distributing downloads in Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the best way to implement in Spark this:

```
def read_json(url):
  resp = requests.get(url)
  resultRDD = sc.parallelize(json.loads(resp.content))
  df = jsonRDD.toDF()
  hiveContext.createDataFrame(resultRDD, df.schema).registerTempTable("tmp_tbl_1")
  hiveContext.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE `sc1`.`tbl_data` SELECT * FROM tmp_tbl_1")

urlsRDD = sc.parallelize(["valid-url1.json","valid-url2.json","valid-url3.json"])
urlsRDD.map(read_json)
```

How to distribute the `requests.get(url)` on the cluster?

How to use SparkContext / HiveContext / xContext on map function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use SparkContext / HiveContext / xContext on map function

You cannot. It is not possible to access `SparkContext` / `SQLContext` on the worker.

> How to distribute the requests.get(url) on the cluster?

Given the logic you shouldn't. Since insert is not idempotent, any failure will result in inconsistent state of table. This is a job for highly granular task manager (like Celery) or workflow manager (like Luigi or Airflow).